# How to repalce navbar menu with hamburger icon in small screens?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a navbar which turns into icon in small sizes and remains full menu in large screens. It is changing as icon in mobile screens but in large screens, the icon is still visible until refreshing.

```
  <div class="mobileMenu">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">button a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">button b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">button c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">button d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

```
let mbp = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 425px)");
setInterval(() => {
  if (mbp.matches) {
    $(".mobileMenu ul").hide();
    $(".mobileMenu").html('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>');
  } else {
    $(".mobileMenu ul").show();
  }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use css media query?

```css
@media (max-width: 425px) {
  .mobileMenu ul {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 425px) {
  .mobileMenu .fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobileMenu">
  <i class="fa fa-bars">fa-bars</i>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">button a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">button b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">button c</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">button d</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```